# Lytebox in Center of Screen

Tags: css, center, lytebox

Is there any way to set Lytebox (http://lytebox.com/) to open in the center of the screen (center middle) instead of the top center?

Answer (score 2):

adding something like `#lbMain { top: 25% !important; }` to your stylesheet should do it. Toy with the % value to get it where you want it. It won't be dead center but you can get close.

Comment: For Grouped Images, it got some problem. Once press next to another images (height of the image more than previous image), it cannot preview whole images.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It works fine on the lytebox site. Do you have an example?

Comment: It work fine in center after click the link. But, once I click the next button [Image 1](http://tammy.6te.net/example/lightbox1.JPG), my next image cannot preview or fit the screen.[Image2](http://tammy.6te.net/example/lightbox2.JPG)

Comment: Bummer. The best advice I think I could give you would be to use a different modal plugin. It seems like lytebox is, by its nature, designed to reside at the top of the page. If I may recommend colorbox (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox), it's really easy to implement and use and has a pretty great set of options.

Comment: but I want to use it in an iframe environment, colorbox can't support on it. Another encounter problem [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940897/open-colorbox-group-images-from-iframe-to-parent-window)

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're looking for, this question has changed significantly and should either be closed or retitled. If you're looking to open an iframe in colorbox, you can absolutely do that with the `iframe` option in colorbox.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I mean something like this, please look for the preview [example](http://tammy.6te.net/example/lightbox3.JPG).