# Open colorbox (Group Images) from iframe to parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe, colorbox

I plan to use Colorbox (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) in an iframe environment, how can launch the viewer from within an iframe?

Below link is works on iframe content/youtube, but I want using Group images. So it will can click next/prev images. 
http://blog.svnlabs.com/open-colorbox-from-iframe-to-parent-window/

Is that anyway can solve this?

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question more for any good help to come...

Comment: @KevinM I want to open colorbox in parent window from iFrame with grouping images. But I can't find out any solution about it. I found this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/Open$20colorbox$20in$20parent$20from$20iFrame$20with$20grouping$20images/colorbox/cmDZYtGxwh0/mzzdlvHiU7IJ)
, but seem like it's not working for me. 
Below link is working on iFrame only but not grouping images.
http://blog.svnlabs.com/open-colorbox-from-iframe-to-parent-window/